# Error - suexec:notice

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, https

I had Launched an Apache PHP application on Amazon EC2 instance. And we are terminating using AWS ELB. We are using ACM self-signed certificate.

getting some error:

```
[suexec:notice] [pid 3187] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: 
/usr/sbin/suexec)
```

And also am not much aware of apache, Please help me out to solve this and explain why it is.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by your Apache web server continuing to load mod_ssl and the server is not configured correct for SSL.

At the server console run "`sudo a2dismod ssl`".

Restart apache "`sudo service apache2 restart`".

To re-enable "`sudo a2enmod ssl`".